# GeoApiContext and DirectionsApiRequest not found

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, directions, geoapi

What dependencies are needed for these two classes to be used within my Android App? Below, is my current build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

    //UI Dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'

    //testing frameworks
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"

    //API Dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'

    //Directions API
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
}
```

However, I still get "Cannot resolve symbol: GeoApiContext" and "Cannot resolve symbol: DirectionsApiRequest".

I have added Google Maven repository, but no luck:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

I was missing dependency `implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.3'`

in my build.gradle file

Comment: Latest versions can be found here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.maps/google-maps-services